# Get and change safe senders list and blocked senders list via EWS

Tags: c#, c++, powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

All email mailboxes are keep on Exchange (2013) Server.

I'm working on application which can read and add/remove entries from blocked and safe sender lists on Exchange Server.
As I found in Microsoft Docs these lists are keep in mailbox object on Exchange Server ([Exchange Safelist Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/safelist-aggregation-exchange-2013-help)) and I can get these lists via Exchange Powershell command:

`(Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration someUsername).BlockedSendersAndDomains`

Is it possible to get these information via EWS or any other way from C++, C# or Java level?

Comment: See the EWS API docs for direction.

Comment: You can do it in a limited way with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-add-and-remove-email-addresses-from-blocked-senders-list-by-using-ews